# Docker image build fails to explode jar

Tags: java, linux, bash, docker, shell

I'm trying to create a multi-stage Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jre-slim-buster AS build

... additional commands


RUN mkdir -p target/exploded && (cd target/exploded; jar -xf ../*.jar)
```

But it fails when trying to explode the .jar file, it is present under the target directory:

[image]

```
 => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN mkdir -p target/exploded && (cd
 target/exploded; jar -xf ../*.jar)
 /bin/sh: 1: jar: not found
 ------
 executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mkdir -p target/exploded && (cd target/exploded; 
 jar -xf ../*.jar)]: exit code: 127
```

Comment: jar command is installed in the container?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to debug where the `jar` command is, in order to fully address it in your call by a:

```
RUN find / -name jar
```

The remove this line and prepend the found path to your `jar` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm including **Spring Cloud Contract** as a dependency, it generates a **...stubs.jar** file, causing a Docker conflict as it can't choose the proper jar to be exploded, now I'm updating the Dockerfile to target the correct .jar file.